# What is keeping indoor basil from thriving?

Tags: diagnosis, indoors, basil

I have been trying to figure out how to successfully grow basil indoors, but I have constantly struggled to help the basil thrive.

I have two LED grow lights, and the different places on the plants read between 7k and 20k lux. They get light for 16 hours a day on a timer. The temperature in this room is about 73F. Soil pH is slightly acidic. The soil has very low salinity. I have been using a 20-20-20 fertilizer heavily diluted in water, but haven't seen much reaction from the plants to either more or less fertilizer. The one time the plants did much better is when I propagated the basil from clippings and had them in water. The clippings in plain tap water looked much greener, but after transplanting into soil they started acting more like the rest of the basil. These basil plants were originally grown from seed about 9 months ago, so maybe now the plants are just too old? But they have never really thrived even earlier, either, although they did seem to do a bit better when they were younger.

I am really confused! Am I missing anything?

[image: large basil pot]
[image: small basil pot]

Comment: I think the need more moisture.